# Постепенное увеличение скорости шара в пинг понг Юнити

Tags: c#, unity3d

При создании 2D игры по типу пинг понга на Юнити возник вопрос как можно увеличивать скорость движения шарика, скажем на 1, через каждые 10 секунд времени игры? В скрипте для шарика объявил float speed, за движение шарика отвечает сторока:

```
 transform.Translate(direction * speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Попробовать что-то типа такого:

```
public float speedIncreasingDelay = 10F;
private float speedDelta = 1f;


void Start() {
    StartCoroutine("speedUp");
}

IEnumerator speedUp() {             
    while (true) {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(speedIncreasingDelay);
        speed += speedDelta;                 
    }
}
```

- `speedIncreasingDelay` - величина, каждые N секунд увеличивать скорость
- `speedDelta` - на сколько увеличивать

Comment: А чем вариант `StartCoroutine("speedUp")` лучше, чем `StartCoroutine(SpeedUp())`, ведь если мы изменим имя SpeedUp, то можем забыть изменить строку?

Comment: А я разве где-то написал, что какой-то вариант лучше?

Comment: Хорошо, тогда имеет ли он какие-либо преимущества? Опять же, при изменении имени SpeedUp  возникнет ошибка, я прав?

Comment: Если кто-то боится ошибок - может делать по-другому) Преимуществ никаких нет)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский в вопросе привел скорректированный вариант кода, но появилась следующая ошибка

Comment: @Вячеслав нельзя так делать. если есть доуточнения по вопросу - просто надо либо коммент оставить либо новый вопрос. Потому что в итоге получается что я ответил ни на что)  А у вас проблема в том, что вы рестарт делаете (`Restart.Instance.RestartLevel();`). И объект с корутиной понятное дело уничтожается

Comment: @АлексейШиманский хорошо учту замечание. Касаемо рестарта вроде понятно, но до рестарта по идее увеличение скорости должно же работать?

Comment: @Вячеслав а вы временно закоментируйте рестарт и посмотрите)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Да, так работает, но первые 10 секунд шар просто стоит без движения, как тогда изменить, чтобы он начинал двигаться скажем со скорости 2 и до 12?

Comment: @Вячеслав логично что а) задать начальную скорость б) прописать условие, что если скорость >= 12 то остановить корутину

Comment: @АлексейШиманский да работает, спасибо, на удивление с рестартом увеличение скорости работает тоже